# How to recover the values of two columns with the same name?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, alias

I have this query:

```
$query
    ->select(array('a.id', 'a.alias', 'b.category_id', 'b.item_id', 'c.id', 'c.name', 'c.alias'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__zoo_category', 'a'))
    ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__zoo_category_item', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.category_id') . ')')
    ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__zoo_item', 'c') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('b.item_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('c.id') . ')')
    ->where($db->quoteName('a.alias') . ' = \'chubut\'');
```

As you can see, I'm recovering 2 alias: **a.alias** and **c.alias**.
I need the browser displays 2 alias.

If I make a *echo* to **$value->alias**, the browser prints the c.alias, not the a.alias. Where is a.alias? How do I get it?

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$resultado = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
    echo "alias: $value->alias";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using "AS" keyword? Like:
`... c.alias AS alias2 ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AS` keyword.

Try this:

```
$query
    ->select('a.id, a.alias AS cat_alias, b.category_id, b.item_id, c.id, c.name, c.alias AS item_alias')

    ...
    ...

;
```

Then

```
foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
    echo "alias: $value->cat_alias";
}
```

**Note:** Using `AS` keyword is not mandatory, so you can omit it. For example:

```
$query->select('a.id, a.alias cat_alias, c.alias item_alias');
```

Comment: The idea is to put an alias to an alias!
Wow great! It worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :) ! Yes, for your problem, you must use alias of alias!